# Shortening MySQL code for getting more information based on variable

Tags: php, mysql

I'm building a site that requires users to choose a bunch of countries. They are save to the database as three letter codes. On visiting a page, the user's selections are pulled. At this point, I want to process these coded selections through another table to get their full names.

I have some ideas on how to do it, but don't want to have 100 lines of code running this seemingly straight forward action.

Table *users*: Preferences by email.

Table *country*: Country Names by Country Code.

**USERDATA.PHP**

```
// Step One: Get User Preferences
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email' LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $w1A = $row['1A'];
    $w2A = $row['2A'];
    $w1B = $row['1B'];
    $w2B = $row['2B'];
    ...
    $w1G = $row['1G'];
    $w2G = $row['2G'];
    $w1H = $row['1H'];
    $w2H = $row['2H'];
    }

// Step Two: Get Country Name
$query = "SELECT name FROM country WHERE code = '$w1A' LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $n1A = $row['code'];
  }
// Then repeat Step Two for all the countries?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is to have a third table, `usercountry`, with two fields: userID and countryCode.  It contains one row per user-country, so instead of having 20 columns in your user table each containing a code, you have 20 rows per user in the usercountry table.

Then you can do:

```
SELECT users.name AS userName,
  country.name AS countryName
  FROM users
  LEFT JOIN usercountry ON usercountry.userID = users.userID
  LEFT JOIN country ON country.code = usercountry.countryCode
  WHERE users.email = 'myemail@somewhere'
```

This returns a result set with 20 rows, each containing one countryName field.